# Jenkins invalid target release

Tags: java, jenkins

Tengo un proyecto con java 11 y al realizar la compilación en jenkins me arroja un error de "invalid target release: 11". Al realizar la compilación en el IDE no tengo ningún problema.

Comment: En la documentacion oficial de Jenkins viene una wiki sobre como usar jenkins con java 11 https://jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/jenkins-on-java-11/

Comment: Es posible que tengas problemas con alguno de los plugin. Realizaste alguna actualización del servidor que soporta la instancia de Jenkins?

Answer (score 2):

En caso de si estas usando Maven debas indicar en tu pom.xml de esta manera.

pom.xml

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>11</source> 
            <target>11</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.